# webpack config for js with ng-annotate-loader & babel-loader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I have tried 2 ways to use ng-annotate and babel loaders same time for my *.js files.

```
{   //this worked
    test: /\.js?$/,
    loader: 'ng-annotate!babel?presets[]=es2015'
}

{   // this broke down
    test: /\.js?$/,
    loader: 'ng-annotate!babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015']
    }
}
```

Why the second loader config won't work? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found this as the solution:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  loaders: ['ng-annotate', 'babel?presets[]=es2015']
},
```

I believe it's something to do with how webpack loads the query/presets. It doesn't know which loader the preset applies to.

See [babel-loader options](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options), it shows how to pass options as a query string